# Sybase Run-time Error Handling

Tags: sql, error-handling, sybase, syntax-error

I want to handle my `CONVERT(real, var)` statement against incorrect input like 'gg'. As you know, it gives a syntax error when you try to run `CONVERT(real, 'gg')`. How can I handle this and prevent the program from halting?

Answer (score 0):

`Convert()` functions works when datatype are compatible. Character string can't be convert into numbers, real in this case. So it is better to use `IF` condition, before converting to `real`, to check whether input value is number string or character string.

Comment: i'm looking into "how to check if an input is number string or character string"